# @FetchRequest in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I keep getting the following error when running my SwiftUI app with Core Data.

```
[error] error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Movie' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?
```

In my MovieAppApp file I have the following code.

```
 var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MoviesScreen().environment(\.managedObjectContext, CoreDataManager.shared.viewContext)
        }
    }
```

And finally, in the MoviesScreen I use the @FetchRequest as shown below:

```
struct MoviesScreen: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Movie.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)])
    var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
    
    var body: some View {
        List(movies, id: \.self) { movie in
            Text(movie.title ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

The CoreDataManager is shown below:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    private init() {
        
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MovieAppModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        print(directories[0])
    }
    
    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext 
    }
    
}
```

Why do I keep getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should get your **model** from `main` bundle, and pass that to `NSPersistentContainer` initialiser.

Try below code-:

```
class DataControllers:ObservableObject{
   
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory:Bool = false) {
       
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Main", managedObjectModel: DataController.model)
        
        if inMemory{
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
       
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error{
                fatalError("fatal error loading data:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
           
        }
    }
    
    static let model: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Main", withExtension: "momd") else{
            fatalError("Failed to locate model file.")
        }
        
        guard let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load model file.")
        }
        
        return managedObjectModel
    }()
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that if I use the exact same code and not use @NSFetchRequest and create request manually then it works as expected.